# Setting combo box's scroll area border/background color in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

I'm having trouble getting the drop down of a QComboBox to have the same color all around. When I click on my combo box, this appears

[image]

I do not want the white border color that appears to be part of the scroller of this drop down. However, I can't figure out what this white border belongs to! Is it the QAbstractScrollArea of the QComboBox? Is it the QListView? Is it the QScrollArea, QScroller or QScrollBar? I've tried setting background colors/border colors for all of these properties but to no avail. The following is a stripped down version of my app so that you can just copy and paste this into python and have it run (unfortunately I really couldn't shorten it any further, so sorry for how long it is!)

```
import sys
import os
import urllib.request

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()

        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.init_combobox()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.show()

    def init_combobox(self):

        data_solid = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/fbrdSkv.png').read()
        pixmap_solid = QPixmap()
        pixmap_solid.loadFromData(data_solid)

        data_dashed = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/gI9oHKm.png').read()
        pixmap_dashed = QPixmap()
        pixmap_dashed.loadFromData(data_dashed)

        data_dotted = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/AAu4TrX.png').read()
        pixmap_dotted = QPixmap()
        pixmap_dotted.loadFromData(data_dotted)

        cbox = QComboBox()
        cbox.setObjectName('linestylecbox')
        cbox.setFixedSize(75, 25)
        cbox.addItem(QIcon(pixmap_solid), '')
        cbox.addItem(QIcon(pixmap_dashed), '')
        cbox.addItem(QIcon(pixmap_dotted), '')
        cbox.setIconSize(QSize(75, 25))
        cbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 50, 0)
        cbox.setStyleSheet('''
            QComboBox#linestylecbox 
            {
                background-color: black;
                color: black;
                font: 10px Lucida Sans;
                border: 0px solid black;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            QComboBox#linestylecbox::drop-down 
            {
                border: 0px;
                border-top: 0px;
                border-color: black;
                background-color: black;
                font: 10px Lucida Sans;
            }

            QComboBox#linestylecbox QListView
            {
                background-color: black;
                color: black;
            }
        ''')

        self.vlayout.addWidget(cbox)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I get: https://imgur.com/a/AOby4zo, and it does not match the image it shows. What is the error?

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is a mac vs. windows thing? I am on Mac. There is no error, it is more that I just want to set the white border color to black.